# Erasing a specific selected portion of a bitmap

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am building a Flash Paint application. The basic structure is this.

I have two layers namely `topLayer_mc` and `bottomLayer_mc`. The actual vector drawing is drawn on the top layer and `onmouseUp` of the tool, a bitmap copy of the vector graphics on the top layer is taken and added as a bitmap to the bottom layer. The top layer is cleared subsequently. It is working for the pencil tool.

Now I need to create an eraser tool. This is where things get tricky. In the application there is an option to save the image as png, so alpha has top be preserved. So the coventional method of draw a brush using the vector and using the draw method of bitmap will not work. Of course, on a visual level it would work if the brush drawn using the vector is to have the same color as that of the background.

What I need is to excatly erase the pixels.

Now I have created a brush tool using the conventional technique and clearing is possible but what I need is to exactly erase the pixels. Is there some technique to draw this ?

This is the code that I am using:

I have also uploaded the swf and source code,

http://bobbythecoder.blogspot.com/2011/04/doubt-bitmap.html

When trying out, please draw all over the stage using the pencil (press Pencil button and start drawing)

The source fla is also provided,

[http://www.easy-share.com/1914823453/Paint Brush Expt.fla](http://www.easy-share.com/1914823453/Paint%20Brush%20Expt.fla)

I have been trying hard for some time so it would be greatly appreciated if you can assist.

`topLayer_mc` and `bottomLayer_mc` have alpha set to zero now.

I have also not created a draggable brush, just two hard coded positions are cleared. To draw using pencil, just press the pencil button and draw. To clear, just press the eraser button.

What I need is a technique to erase the pixels in the area marked by a brush not just drawing over it.

Comment: @Timofei Davydik  . Sorry brother I was not aware of it. I started using stack regularly only recently. Extremly sorry.

Answer (score 2):

If you pick through the AS3 documentation you'll find a few things that are significant. First of all, you're trying to draw with blendmode "erase" (**BlendMode.ERASE**), which only works if the DisplayObject parent Bitmap has it's blendMode changed from **flash.display.BlendMode.NORMAL** to **flash.display.BlendMode.LAYER**. If you do intend to use erase mode, I recommend using the constant flash.display.BlendMode.ERASE rather than hardcoding the literal "erase", for forwards compatibility reasons.

But.. you might not be intending to use **BlendMode.ERASE**, did you pick that intentionally with full knowledge of how it works? It is not necessary to use this blend mode with BitmapData. It should be sufficient for your erase tool to use **BlendMode.NORMAL** with your BitmapData.draw() operation, and draw transparent pixels of color 0x00000000, which you will get by specifying beginFill(0x000000, 0);

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for answering. But I tried changing it to mcBMPD1.draw(topLayer_mc.draw_mc, null, null, BlendMode.NORMAL);
and gfx.beginFill( 0x000000, 0). If I draw a line on the stage it still does not appear to have been cleared. I hope you had seen the code.

Comment: I looked at your example FLA. There is no mystery why it's not working :-) Look at your eraserInit function--you're creating a bitmap called mcBMP1, drawing into it, then never doing anything with it. The circles you see are just the ones you draw to "gfx", your mcBMPD1 and mcBMP1 bitmap objects are completely unused and available to be GC'd as soon as you exit from eraserInit();

Comment: I'm pretty sure you meant to draw to the bitmap that already exists (mcBMP you attached to bottomLayer_mc), but you don't save a reference to that so you can't easily do it (apart from something silly like bottomLayer_mc.getChildAt(0) as Bitmap... save a reference and update that bitmap rather than adding a new one to bottomLayer_mc with each pencil draw mouseup (huge memory usage issue there)

Comment: OK, I looked at your FLA, and I think I worked out what it is you're trying to do--and it's not simple. You can disregard my response above, the beginFill with alpha=0 does not do what I expected. What you really want to do is essentially write zero-value pixels into just the alpha channel of your bottom layer bitmap. There's no easy way to do this for arbitrary shapes like circles (only for rects or individual pixels). There is undoubtedly some combination of copyChannel extraction, copyPixels addition and copyChannel back that will work, but it will take some trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

Drawing transparent pixels (any colour with 0 alpha) should do the trick!

Comment: Hi Dain. I hope you had seen the code. I just changed there the line gfx.beginFill(0xcccccc, 1);   to   gfx.beginFill(0xcccccc, 0); but it did not help. I hope that was what you meant. Or is there something else I need to do.

Comment: It did not work because of the BitmapData.draw() call in your code specifying BlendMode.ERASE instead of BlendMode.NORMAL. I added an answer with a more complete explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a **bitmap**, fill it with a `green rectangle`, and then draw a `red fill circle` in it. Now, you can use **copyChannel**, use the **source channel** as `GREEN`, and the **destination channel** as `Alpha`. So, it will end up creating an erase effect with a **circular brush**.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd create third transparent clip for erasing. When you click on it while holding erasing tool just put whight circle on it.